# Google Apps MX for User Accounts, Custom Postfix for Sending only, same domain

Tags: linux, email, postfix, g-suite

I have a google apps business account which provides the use of gmail's mx servers. I would like to use this for users to send/receive email. However, I have a specific need to send bulk emails on a regular basis, and according to Google's [Sending Limits](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166852), we can only send 2K emails a day using their mail server.

I have a vps which has a static IP (and port 25 unblocked), which I can install and configure postfix. I would like to use this mail server to send mail so I am not limited to 2K a day. I am willing to purchase a SSL cert to ensure encrypted connections to the mail server, and from the mail server to email providers (gmail, hotmail).

Has anyone implemented this hybrid approach, if so am I on the right track? Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As long as you've got SPF and DKIM configured properly for it, they won't care what server's doing the sending.

Comment: Could you convert to an answer with more information about the acronyms you stated, and why they are relevant?

Comment: Rather than listen to me, the best resource I've seen is http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: Awesome I'll check it out. Thanks for the response. Wanted to give you credit via accepted answer if it worked out.